# Use both associated value and computed property of error enum

Tags: swift, error-handling, enums, try-catch

I have my error written as such:

```
public enum ParseError: LocalizedError {
    case badURL(_ urlString: String)

    public var errorDescription: String? {
        switch self {
        case .badURL:
            return String.invalidURL
        }
    }
}
```

Since I have only one case, I don't care to create multiple patterns in my calling code:

```
    do {
        let url = try urlString.constructURL()
        UIApplication.shared.open(url)
    } catch {
        Alert().showError(error.errorDescription, subTitle: urlString) // trying to get the associated value here
    }
```

I want to do something like:

```
catch let error = error as ParseError(let urlString)
```

but obviously, that's not possible. How do I get the value of the enum itself along with its associated value in the statement?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could think of is to add a `urlString` property to the error type,

```
extension ParseError {
    var urlString: String? {
        switch self {
        case .badURL(let x): return x
        }
    }
}
```

Then catch the error like this:

```
do {
    let url = try urlString.constructURL()
    UIApplication.shared.open(url)
} catch let error as ParseError {
    Alert().showError(error.errorDescription, subTitle: error.urlString)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is an error catching syntax exactly for this case.
I adopted the code so it runs in Playground.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
public enum ParseError: LocalizedError {
    case badURL(_ urlString: String)

    public var errorDescription: String? {
        switch self {
        case .badURL:
            return "invalidURL"
        }
    }
}

let strForURL = "www.swift.org"
do {
    if let url = URL(string: strForURL) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url)
        // Temporaly line used to fire error
        throw ParseError.badURL(strForURL) // FIXME: - remove in production
    }
    else {
        throw ParseError.badURL(strForURL)
    }
} catch ParseError.badURL(let badURLString) {

        print("Alert \(ParseError.badURL("").errorDescription ?? "") \(badURLString)")
    //Alert().showError(error.errorDescription, subTitle: urlString) // FIXME: - show alerts you want
}
```

If you need **error** itself too, here's another variant for catch block:

```
} catch let error as ParseError {
    if case .badURL(let badURLString) = error {
        print("Alert \(error.errorDescription) \(badURLString)")
    }
    //Alert().showError(error.errorDescription, subTitle: urlString) // FIXME: - show alerts you want
}
```